# Delete output parts

Tags: php

I want to be able to delete some output buffer parts. So that considering this code:

```
function over_all($string) {
    if (OVER_ALL_ENABLED) { 

        # Stop output buffer
        # Clean output buffer

        echo $string;

        # Restart output buffer
    }
}

ob_start();

echo 'This is phrase 1<br>';
over_all('I don\'t want to see Phrase 1<br>');
echo 'This is phrase 2';
over_all('I don\'t want to see Phrase 2');
```

If I set `OVER_ALL_ENABLED` to true it will print:

> I don't want to see Phrase 1
>   I don't want to see Phrase 2

else:

> This is phrase 1
>   This is phrase 2

Could you replace comments with correct PHP functions?

Comment: [PHP Manual: Output buffering control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Comment: If you don't want to see the phrase in output - just don't echo it. That's so simple. Fix the root of the issue.

Comment: @Jeff Pigarelli: sure. And I still don't see any reason to even try to output anything that isn't supposed to be returned to the client. That's about bad design, not complexity.

Comment: @Jeff Pigarelli: as I said - it's about bad design. For first - retrieve and process the data, after that - output it. Don't mix the data retrieval and it's presentation. Following such idea you'll not get the case in the question.

Comment: @Jeff Pigarelli: the simplest way to get the idea - is to dive into MVC (it is not panacea, but the most popular pattern and suitable for most cases). So following MVC you'll move all the data retrieval/processing into Model layer and will format the output in the View layer. Controller is a "glue" layer that combines it. So Controller creates Models (the place when some exception may occur) and passes the results to Views.

Comment: @Jeff Pigarelli: I don't have enough information to say something particular but personally I'm sure that there should be only one place that echoes the output.

Comment: @Jeff Pigarelli: sorry if some of my words sounds rude...

Comment: @zerkms, You were right from the beginning. It was all about my beginner's arrogance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff, I think that this code must work

```
function over_all($string) {
    if (OVER_ALL_ENABLED) { 
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $string;
        ob_start();
    }
}
```

But if you run it under web server, and gz enable in it, that it will be buffering there

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ob_end_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ob_Clean()](http://si.php.net/ob_clean) to erase anything that is in the output buffer.

Your function should look like this then:

```
function over_all($string) {
    if (OVER_ALL_ENABLED) {
        Ob_Clean ();
        echo $string;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will delete also "I don't want to see Phrase 1".

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. I'm afraid there is no simple solution then. The easiest way would be to just output what you actually want to output. Another solution could be to have two output variables, and then write to those two variables, and then at the end of the script echo the one you want. Sorry, no magic functions available for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine, it should be something like:

```
$new_output = "";

function over_all($string) {
    if (OVER_ALL_ENABLED) {
        $new_output .= $string;
        Ob_Clean ();
    }
};

ob_start();

echo 'This is phrase 1<br>';
over_all('I don\'t want to see Phrase 1<br>');
echo 'This is phrase 2';
over_all('I don\'t want to see Phrase 2');

echo $new_output;

ob_end_flush();
```

the `$new_output` variable will be like you would have a second buffer (one that is not cleaned by `ob_clean`).